# WordPress find page names

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using wordpress and I would like to create an array which holds the name's of each page.

Eg my wordpress site currently has the pages, "home", "Adam", "Fred"

so I would like an array which holds

```
$pages = array("home", "Adam", "Fred")
```

Thanks for your time and help

Comment: Please provide what you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code. this is you want.

```
$pages = get_pages($args); 
 foreach ( $pages as $page ) {
    $pagesArray[] = $page->post_title;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, 
I posted the following and got an error am I doing something wrong?

$pages = get_pages(); 
 foreach ( $pages as $page ) {
    $pagesArray[] = $page->post_title;
}
echo $pages[0];

Comment: Catchable fatal error: Object of class WP_Post could not be converted to string in C:\wamp\www\learning\wp-content\themes\practice\page-home.php on line 21

Comment: remove this code echo $pages[0]; and use print_r($pagesArray); or echo $pagesArray[0]

Comment: Sorry this was my first question, I did not realise the green tick option, how would I sort the array by the "order value"?

Comment: order value means page title?

Comment: in wordpress if you click on a edit for an individual page there is a place at the bottom called order where you can input a number

Comment: you can use $page->ID

Comment: Thanks menu order is what I was looking for but your answer helped me understand $page so I was able to find it, thanks so much for your help

Answer (score 1):

```
$pages = array("home", "Adam", "Fred");
```

you missed the `"` after `Adam`.